# SQL Injection or Server.HTMLEncode or both? Classic ASP

Tags: security, asp-classic, sql-injection, html-encode

People say to prevent SQL Injection, you can do one of the following (amongst other things):

1. Prepare statements (parameterized)
2. Stored procedures
3. Escaping user input

I have done item 1, preparing my statements, but I'm now wondering if I should escape all user input as well. Is this a waste of time seeming as I have prepared statements or will this double my chances of prevention?

Comment: you can also validate user input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly the first step to prevent SQL Injection attacks is to always use parameterised queries, never concatenate client supplied text into a SQL string.  The use of stored procedures is irrelevant once you have taken the step to parameterise.

However there is a secondary source of SQL injection where SQL code itself (usually in an SP) will have to compose some SQL which is then EXEC'd.  Hence its still possible to be vunerable to injection even though your ASP code is always using parameterised queries.  If you can be certain that none of your SQL does that **and will never** do that then you are fairly safe from SQL Injection.  Depending on what you are doing and what version to SQL Server you are using there are occasions where SQL compositing SQL is unavoidable.

With the above in mind a robust approach may require that your code examines incoming string data  for patterns of SQL.  This can be fairly intense work because attackers can get quite sophisticated in avoiding SQL pattern detection.  Even if you feel the SQL you are using is not vunerable it useful to be able to detect such attempts even if they fail.  Being able to pick that up and record additional information about the HTTP requests carrying the attempt is good.

Escaping is the most robust approach, in that case though **all** the code that uses the data in you database must understand the escaping mechanim and be able to unescape the data to make use of it.  Imagine a Server-side report generating tool for example, would need to unescape database fields before including them in reports.

`Server.HTMLEncode` prevents a different form of Injection.  Without it an attacker could inject HTML (include javascript) into the output of your site.  For example, imagine a shop front application that allowed customers to review products for other customers to read.  A malicious "customer" could inject some HTML that might allow them to gather information about other real customers who read their "review" of a popular product.

Hence **always** use `Server.HTMLEncode` on all string data retrieved from a database.

Answer (score 3):

It's usually a waste of time to escape your input on top of using parametrized statements. If you are using a database "driver" from the database vendor and you are **only** using parametrized
 statements without doing things like SQL String concatenation or trying to parametrize the actual SQL syntax, instead of just providing variable values, then you are already as safe as you can be.

To sum it up, your best option is to trust the database vendor to know how to escape values inside their own SQL implementation instead of trying to roll your own encoder, which for a lot of DBs out there can be a lot more work then you think.

If on top of this you want additional protection you can try using a SQL Monitoring Solution. There are a few available that can spot out-of-the-ordinary SQL queries and block/flag them, or just try to learn your default app behavior and block everything else. Obviously your mileage may vary with these based on your setup and use-cases.

Answer (score 2):

Back in the day when I had to do classic ASP, I used both methods 2 and 3.  I liked the performance of stored procs better and it helps to prevent SQL injection.  I also used a standard set of includes to filter(escape) user input.  To be truly safe, don't use classic ASP, but if you have to, I would do all three.

Comment: "To be truly safe, don't use classic ASP" can you explain how classic ASP is more vunerable than other technologies we would have to use if we needed to be "truly safe"?

Comment: There a a host of hacks designed specifically for classic ASP.  One of the worst is to force a view of the page source.  If you are running classic ASP and your server isn't locked down hard, you are just waiting to be toast.

Comment: I've been coding for ASP for many years and this is the first I've heard of needing to "lock the server down hard" in order to prevent viewing of ASP source code.  Care to provide any references that corroborate such a claim?

Comment: Remember this one? http://www.governmentsecurity.org/articles/hacking-iis.html there are still servers out there not patched for it.  https://news.hitb.org/node/360

Comment: Thats over a decade old on IIS4!! I don't consider keeping servers up-to-date with latest patches a "hard lock down", thats just basic.  The same will true of other platforms.

Comment: Well, that's from when classic ASP was still current.  Its not that far fetched, the PS hack happened because of an Apache server that was 7 years out of date...

Comment: The reality is that these days ASP is safer than bleeding edge tech.  Any such vunerablilities have long, long since been eliminated so your advice to be "truely safe, don't use classic ASP" is questionable.  Unless you know of another technology which is "truely" guaranteed to be "safe".

Comment: Classic ASP is safer than ASP.NET?  Is that really what you are asserting?

Comment: Would you call ASP.NET a "bleeding" edge techonology?  Would you describe ASP.NET as being "truely safe"?  Many ASP.NET servers (IIS6 and below) still rely on the exact same IIS script handler technology that classis ASP does.  If it were still possible to circumvent this and trick IIS into delivering ASP as static content then the same would be true of any script mapped files like .aspx.
I would not describe ASP classic and ASP.NET as either being more "safe" than the other nor would I describe either as being "truely safe".  Switching replaces one set of vunerablitiies with another.

Comment: The mathematical fact is that the newer and still developing technology is going to be at greater risk of new vunerablities appearing than older unchanging tech.

Answer (score 1):

First, on the injections in general:

Both latter 2 has nothing to do with injection actually.
And the former doesn't cover all the possible issues.

1. Prepared statements are okay until you have to deal with `identifiers`.
2. Stored provedures are vulnerable to injections as well. It is not an option at all.
3. "escaping" "user input" is most funny of them all.

First, I suppose, "escaping" is intended for the **strings** only, not whatever "user input". Escaping all other types is quite useless and will protect nothing.
Next, speaking of strings, you have to escape them all, not only coming from the user input.
**Finally - no, you don't have to use whatever escaping if you are using prepared statements**

Now to your question.

As you may notice, `HTMLEncode` doesn't contain a word "SQL" in it. One may persume then, that **`Server.HTMLEncode` has absolutely nothing to do with SQL injections.**

It is more like another attack prevention, called XSS. Here it seems a more appropriate action and indeed should be used on the untrusted user input.

So, you may use `Server.HTMLEncode` along with prepared statements. But just remember that it's completely different attacks prevention.

You may also consider to use HTMLEncode before actual HTML output, not at the time of storing data.